# Valor agrupado en consulta SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

Tengo una tabla en SQL Server 2008 donde se registran movimientos (ventas y compras) de varios articulo en diferentes almacenes. Se registra la referencia del articulo, la cantidad del movimiento, el almacén y la fecha del movimiento.

```
ARTICULO - ALMACEN - CANTIDAD - FECHA
   REF01 -       1 -        5 - 01/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        2 - 02/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        1 - 02/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 03/01/2019
```

Los datos se muestran agrupados por todos los campos y sumando los movimientos para obtener solo un registro por cada articulo, almacén y fecha.

```
SELECT 
    ARTICULO, 
    ALMACEN, 
    SUM(CANTIDAD) CANTIDAD, 
    FECHA 
FROM 
    MOVIMIENTOS 
GROUP BY ARTICULO, ALMACEN, FECHA

ARTICULO - ALMACEN - CANTIDAD - FECHA
   REF01 -       1 -        5 - 01/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 02/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 03/01/2019
```

El problema es que quiero añadir una columna que me indique la fecha menor de cada conjunto de articulo y almacén.

```
ARTICULO - ALMACEN - CANTIDAD - FECHA       - PRIMERA_FECHA
   REF01 -       1 -        5 - 01/01/2019  - 01/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 02/01/2019  - 01/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 03/01/2019  - 01/01/2019
```

No me sirve usar el MIN ya que, al estar agrupando por fecha, me devuelve el mismo valor que tiene la columna fecha.

```
SELECT 
    ARTICULO, 
    ALMACEN, 
    SUM(CANTIDAD) CANTIDAD, 
    FECHA, 
    MIN(FECHA) PRIMERA_FECHA 
FROM 
    MOVIMIENTOS 
GROUP BY ARTICULO, ALMACEN, FECHA

ARTICULO - ALMACEN - CANTIDAD - FECHA       - PRIMERA_FECHA
   REF01 -       1 -        5 - 01/01/2019  - 01/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 02/01/2019  - 02/01/2019
   REF01 -       1 -        3 - 03/01/2019  - 03/01/2019
```

Lo he conseguido haciendo un JOIN con un consulta articulo, almacén y fecha agrupando por articulo y almacén y mostrando la fecha como MIN.

```
SELECT 
    ARTICULO, 
    ALMACEN, 
    SUM(CANTIDAD) CANTIDAD, 
    FECHA, 
    MIN_FECHA 
FROM 
    MOVIMIENTOS 
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
        MIN(FECHA) MIN_FECHA,   
        ARTICULO, 
        ALMACEN 
    FROM 
        MOVIMIENTOS 
    GROUP BY ARTICULO, ALMACEN
) REGISTROS_PRIMER_MOVIMIENTO ON MOVIMIENTOS.ARTICULO = REGISTROS_PRIMER_MOVIMIENTO.ARTICULO AND MOVIMIENTOS.ALMACEN = REGISTROS_PRIMER_MOVIMIENTO.ALMACEN 
GROUP BY ARTICULO, ALMACEN, FECHA, MIN_FECHA
```

De esta forma consigo la información pero quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo que no sea esta para comparar el rendimiento de la consulta ya que es un servidor que va bastante justo de recursos.

Comment: Varias cosas. Imposible saber si hay otra forma sin ver lo que hiciste hasta ahora y tu modelo. Y la otra pregunta es, si esa forma anda (y en general suele ser la forma en que se hace), porque querrias otra forma?

Comment: He incluido las consultas Sql y un ejemplo del contenido de la tabla. Espero no haber cometido ningún error. Simplemente quería saber si había otra forma de hacerlo para ver el rendimiento de la consulta en base de datos ya que es una maquina que va muy justa de recursos.

Comment: A mi no solo me parece una excelente solución, me parece que es "la solución". Yo con frecuencia me encuentro con situaciones similares y el join con una subconsulta es lo más limpio y rápido. Entiendo que haces un `LEFT JOIN` para que hay combinaciones de Almacén y artículo que no tienen movimientos.